# Wrong value for percentage between two numbers, powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, math, percentage

I've to calculate, in powershell script (5.1), the percentage between 2 numbers and then, comapare it with a threshold (5%), I've found this method:

```
(12540/25080).tostring("P")
50%
```

But, if I try with numbers that has decimal after point, result is wrong:

```
(301/292).tostring("P")
103,08%
```

Other strange thing is, if I compare 103,08% with 5%, 5% is bigger than 103,08%!

```
$foo = (301/292).tostring("P")
$foo -lt "5%"
True
```

How can I get correct value for compare percentage digits?

EDIT:

As TheMadTechnician and others says, I've tried to compare strings not digits... well, therefore it does not exist a "formula" that allow me to calculate percentage directly without manipulating the type of data?

Comment: You are comparing strings, not numbers. Operations are based off the left hand value type, and you explicitly run the `.ToString()` method to create `$foo`, so `$foo.GetType()` shows that it is a string. That's only going to be useful for display purposes, not for calculations.

Comment: in terms of `103.08%` being smaller than `5%` its because you are comparing strings, not numbers

Comment: What do you mean by "result is wrong" when `103,08%` ? Also, you need to strip the `%` and convert them to a double or integer for a proper comparison

Comment: I would say the result wrong in the case of `(200/100).ToString("P")`, it should be 200% thats what I got when I ran that exact command in powershell).  The other result is correct it seems.  So what result would you expect from `(301/292).ToString("P")`?

Comment: @frankM_DN, sorry, you're right, I've copied and pasted the wrong example! Fix it now

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, You're right! My own first example confused me... forgive me

Comment: The simplest way of handling this is to forget the percentage sign exists at all until the final step when you present your values. As long as you're comparing numbers with numbers, there's no problem.

Comment: `$foo = (301/292).tostring("P"); $foo.TrimEnd('%') -as [double] -lt '5%'.TrimEnd('%')`

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon, Hi, in this mode 301/292 becomes 10308 and not 1,xy

Comment: What about using `[double]::Parse($foo.TrimEnd('%'), [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture)` ?

Comment: Either that or `(301/292).ToString("P", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` this method will be better imo

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon, mmh, no, 103,08 it's not good, I prefear:  `$foo = 301/292; $foo = [math]::round($foo,2)`, than compare and, at the end, the `.ToString("P")` method for presenting!